# XPathNavigator select as if current node was root, or validate that an expression is relative to current node

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am trying to write a class, that contains a private `XPathExpression` with functions where users can pass in a `XPathNavigator` or `HtmlNodeNavigator`, which returns also `XPathNavigator` or `HtmlNodeNavigator`.

```
class Demo
{
    private XPathExpression expr;
    public Demo(String xpath)
    {
        expr = XPathExpression.Compile(xpath);
    }

    XPathNavigator GetFirst(XPathNavigator current)
    {
        return current.SelectSingleNode(expr);
    }
}
```

The goal is that these can be used in sequence, so for example

```
String content = "<x><x>abc</x></x>";
var doc = new HtmlDocument(content);
var demo = new Demo("//x");
XPathNavigator root = doc.DocumentNode.CreateNavigator();
XPathNavigator outer = demo.GetFirst(root);
XPathNavigator inner = demo.GetFirst(outer);
```

Here I want that `inner.Value` should equal "abc". However, this doesn't work. The expression `//x` will always select from the root. To make it work, I could change the expression to `.//x`, so that it actually uses the current node.

But is there a way to do this **without modifying the expression** (which is all similar questions use as their answer)? I'm looking for something like `current.AsRoot.SelectSingleNode(expr)`. This would be the best solution for me. Although I would prefer to do this without parsing an entirely new HtmlDocument for efficiency reasons.

If that is not possible, as a backup plan, how could I validate that the expression is actually relative to give feedback to the user? Would simply checking that it starts with `.` cover all cases? I think there are some function calls that could complicate the validation.

Comment: As for "Would simply checking that it starts with . cover all cases?", no, you can write expressions like `x`, `descendant::x` which would in your case give the desired result but don't start with a dot. In any case,  your concept of `AsRoot` does not seem to relate to the XPath concept of a root node. If you want to offer XPath support to users it might be better to educate them on XPath concepts rather than trying to use XPath under the hood to provide some selection mechanism different from XPath.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Education is expensive :) And it's hard to give good feedback if the problem can't be automatically detected. I would like to eliminated potential problems in an automated way if I can. But right now it seems like the only option. Fortunately it's not too complicated.